# what is a transport in ESB

Tags: java, open-source, integration, wso2-esb

I have searched a lot but could not get a proper answer. I'm hoping to write a new adapter for the wso2 esb which will enable to identify a new messaging protocol (not yet supported by wso ESb) . I found out that i have to write a transport for that. I just need to know what does a transport do? should it have the capability of understanding the message using message builders ? and does that component do all the message transformation etc . please explain .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggestion: take a look at [Mulesoft](http://www.mulesoft.com/mule-esb-open-source-esb).  Two examples of "transports" are [JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/overview.html) and [Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqsx.html).

Answer (score 0):

Transport is basically a method of carrying the message .The transport basically a protocoal such as http,https,vfs which carries the message end to end,

To check on WSO2 way Please refer the document "WSO2 Carbon Transports Catalog" at [1].

To write a new transport WSO2 ESB is based on Apache Synapse and it uses Axis2 Transports to provide the transports.
 You can write a new Axis2 transport and plug it to WSO2 ESB. 
You can refer [2] and [3].

[1]. http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/transports/transports-catalog.html

[2] http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/axis2config.html#Receiver

[3] http://synapse.apache.org/transports.html

Thank You,
Dharshana.

Comment: thank you very much for the replies .It helped a lot. Another thing i wanted to know is ,does it handle all the security features added to the message...? please explain

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 Transport (which we use in WSO2 ESB) is at the outer most layer of the SOAP processing engine. Please refer [1] for complete details on that.

To explain more about this. Imagine SMS protocol you need to convert to an Axis2 transport. Here you need to convert the incoming sms message into a SOAP message at the TransportListner and then pass it to the Axis2 engine. In the Transport Listner you can use a MessageBuilder to 
convert the SMS message into a SOAP message.

Similarly when you send the SMS message outside.you can use a message formatter to convert the SOAP message to a SMS message and pass it to TransportSender to a SMS endpoint.

Whether to use a message builder or Transport depend upon the usecase. Imagine you need to consume JSON messages. There you can use any of the existing compatible transport to send JSON message and then use JSON message builder to do that. (Because you can send JSON over HTTP etc.) But if you need to use HTML5 Websockets and send messages over that. You need to define a new Transport since there is no other way to listen and communicate with a web socket.

[1]http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/Axis2ArchitectureGuide.html